# Can I set $Q=e$?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, potential

I'm doing a Millikan's experiment question and it wants me to find the potential difference ($V_p$). So, I rearranged the equation,

$V_p={mgd\over Q}$, where $m=1.11 \times 10^{-13}$ kg, $g=9.8$ N, $d=15$ cm.

And I just wanted to know if I can put $Q$ as $1.6 \times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{C}$ or would I need to calculate it some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely on what you are suppose to be accomplishing.

The point of the Millikan experiment was to *find* $e$, so obviously he couldn't put a particular value in: if the value was know he wouldn't have to run the experiment in the first place.

On the other hand, it you were designing a piece of teaching lab kit or an experiment intended to find a improved value for the constant, you would use the known value to select the operation range of the equipment needs to have to do what is expected of it. However, you would also need to use other values as the experiment doesn't run with only one charge.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the aim of the actual experiment but I'm trying the find the Potential difference and I was wondering if I could put 1.6x10-19 as Q

Comment: Under no circumstances could you possibly use $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ and be correct. If using the known value of $e$ is the right thing to do—something I absolutely can't tell you without sufficient context—you might use $1.6 \times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{\mathbf{C}}$, but without the units it would simply be wrong before you even began.

Answer (score 0):

The Millikan's experiment involved many runs and the Q, which was a charge on oil droplets, was changing from run to run. After many runs, it was determined that the Q was always a multiple of $1.6 \times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{C}$.

Therefore the voltage, $V_p$, required to keep the charged oil droplets suspended in the electrical field of a capacitor, would assume many different discrete values as well and those values would be consistent with the charge, i.e., $V_p=\frac {mgd} {n\times 1.6 \times 10^{-19}\,\mathrm{C}}$.

Comment: Oh ok, the question doesn't say anything about any value n so In this case n=1? Basically meaning that q=1.6x10-19

Comment: Yes, although this is not necessarily a practical value.